# How can I remove an expression that is stored in a variable from a string in base R?

Tags: r, string, replace

For example, I have variable `x = "a1"` while I also have another variable `y = "5a1"`.
How could I make `y = "5"` while still using the x variable?

I tried using `gsub()` with `\ \` but it only seems to work if it is inside double quotes. Is there a variable equivalent for `\ \` ?

Comment: " I know regular expressions and I'm not afraid to use them!!!"  (XKCD) .  It does take a while to learn proper syntax.    Another warning:  console and command processing does strip  backslash characters.  I've written code which needed `\\\\` to properly pass the desired backslash to the low-level functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
x <- "a1"
y <- "5a1"
gsub(pattern = paste0(x, "$"), replacement = "", x = y)
```

`$` is used to match end of string